# Is it worth learning C/C++ before learning Python?

Tags: c++, python, c

I want to learn python, but I feel I should learn C or C++ to get a solid base to build on. I already know some C/C++ as well as other programming languages, which does help. So, should I master C/C++ first?

Comment: As always, it depends. What do you want to get out of it?

Comment: You can pretty much carry on programming with both.

Comment: You might want to ask yourself what exactly it is that C/C++ will teach you that python doesn't and focus on those areas instead. Such as Memory Management, which isn't really C/C++ but an important aspect when programming it.

Comment: @Noodles: I would say that if you want to learn Python (or any other language), the only way to do that is to actually learn it, not just to prepare for learning it. You'll be a better programmer in the long run from mastering multiple languages, but you can still master C and C++ *after* learning Python. And depending what you mean by "learn", you can learn a pretty decent amount of Python in all of a week. What you learn from Python might help your C and C++, anyway.

Comment: Somewhat related Q: [What is an example in which knowing C will make me write better code in any other language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/719997/what-is-an-example-in-which-knowing-c-will-make-me-write-better-code-in-any-other)

Comment: **Opinion based**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my opinion it's better to start learning Python.

I found it easier to learn then C or C++. It has libraries to do virtually anything you might need, and can do essentially anything.

The only reason to use a more difficult language like C/C++ is if you need the performance or are writing code for an embedded system. They are not, however, what you should be learning initially.

C# is a fine language, but nothing beats Python for ease of use.

The scope of Python is quite broad, here are some examples:

- Create a website (Django, etc.)
- Create scripts to do tasks ranging from image manipulation to server maintenance
- Create GUIs (Tkinter, etc.)
- Create games (pygame)
- Scientific computing (SciPy)

Python can interact directly with arbitrary C code, meaning anything which can be done in C, can be done in Python with a little work. Python is popular enough that an interface has been created for virtually everything already.

For a better look at what can be done with python out of the box, take a look at the standard library which comes with python: http://docs.python.org/library/

In short, if it can be done with a computer, and doesn't require the speed of C/C++, it can be done with Python.

Comment: U forgot to mention about Pygtk

Answer (score 4):

I would say it depends on what you want to achieve (cheesy answer...)

The truth is, learning language is a long process. If you plan on learning a language as a step toward learning another language, you're probably wasting your time.

It takes a good year to be proficient with C++, and that is with basic knowledge of algorithms and object concepts. And I only mean proficient, meaning you can get things done, but certainly not expert or anything.

So the real question is, do you want to spend a year learning C++ before beginning to learn Python ?

If the ultimate goal is to program in Python... it doesn't seem worth it.

Answer (score 2):

Real mastery of a language takes time and lots of practice .. its analogous to learning a natural language like French . you have to do a lot of practice in it. but then different languages teach you different programming methodologies.
python and c++ are all object oriented languages so you will be learning the same programming methodology 
The order in which you learn languages doesn't really matter but starting from a lower abstraction to higher one makes understanding some things easier..

Comment: Why *French* ? (pure curiosity)

Comment: @Matthieu: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_theory ? French is canonically "foreign", unless you're you ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you should defiantly learn Python before attempting to learn C or C++ as you will get a better understanding of the core concepts, C++ is mush lower level than Python so you will need to make more commands to do something that you can do in one line in python.